# datetime r abbreviated month

Tags: r, date

I would like to convert this into a date:

```
as.POSIXct("Mar 29 2013", format = "%b %d %Y")
```

I read to use "%b" for abbreviated month.
It seems to work for:

```
as.POSIXct("Apr 29 2013", format = "%b %d %Y")
```

I found `month.abb`, which might be used for checking the month abbreviation. However, it includes "Mar" as the third month.

So my question is, what is wrong with:

```
as.POSIXct("Mar 29 2013", format = "%b %d %Y")
```

Comment: Your locale could be different resulting in the local abbreviation.  Can you check after changing to `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")`

Comment: you are right, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale would be the issue.  One option would be to set the locale after checking

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
```

If it is not English or US, then change it with `Sys.setlocale`

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```